# Карты Карно, минимизация уравнений

Tags: математика, электроника, булева-алгебра

Обязательно ли все единицы должны быть обернуты овалами, или какая-то клетка, если к ней нельзя подобрать пару, может остаться непокрытой овалом?

Comment: Вам нужно понять зачем это вообще делается. Две рядом стоящие единицы обводятся потому, что получается, что при изменении какого-то параметра, значение на выходе не меняется, остается все та же единица, потому ее можно упростить без потери результата. Какой смысл обводить одиновкую единицу, если упростить ее нельзя?

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Просто развеял недопонимание.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, это карта карно:

```
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0
```

У выделенной единицы нет пары, но она всё равно должна обводиться (если вы это имеете виду

```
 1 0 0 1
 1 0 1 0
 0 1 1 0
(1)0 1 0
```